# fakeauthentication is working when my belkin belkin router f7d2301 mac-address filtering enabled

Tags: authentication, wireless, wep, aircrack-ng

Actually i have enabled mac-filtering in my belkin router and the security policy is none and the authentication is open authentication. 
Iam(attacker) using kali linux.
when i done a fakeauth attack on belkin router using this command

```
#aireplay-ng --fakeauth 10 -s <essid> wlan1mon
```

it is working but the router is not denying this attack. but router is denying when the attacker directly connecting without any hacking methods.  why?
Note: in the above command i haven't used any associated client mac but i used the attacker's mac-address only.

and when i observed for an asus router it has wpa2 personal security with open authentication enabled. when i tried the same command to that asus router it also worked without any restriction. and one thing i didn't enabled the mac-filtering in asus router also but the aireplay-ng command is saying that the option will not work for wpa2 encryption. but it got worked for me why?